# Adding to <head> from a CQ component

Tags: aem

In Adobe AEM (former CQ5) what is the best way to be able to add some custom html to  part from a component?

Let's assume that I have a page on which I can place my component in any of the parsys' available (so there're multiple instances possible and I don't know the exact path). I want this component to add some data to  part based on it's content (in addition to it's standard rendering). The problem is that the component's code is executed after the JSP for rendering  so I can't pass the data to render by e.g. a request attribute.

Comment: Good question. I have been wondering about this as well. Adding clientlibs with the component puts them in the middle of the html-body, which is not desirable.  Right now I just add everything in headlibs presuming full control over what limited set of components the user can add.

Answer (score 2):

**Take all of this with a gain of salt, wild speculation follows:**

I'm not 100% sure about this, but I always assumed that the component scripts are executed in the order they are included in the page, which means that by the time a component rendering script gets executed, the page  has already been rendered, making what you are describing impossible.

If you really need this, it should be possible (at least in theory) to write some code that executed in head or headlibs.jsp, and built a list of all components in the page (basically just recursively walk the jcr:content node tree for the page and build a list of the resource types you find) and then based on that include a set client library categories, perhaps by making them hidden properties of the components...or something.

Comment: Similar to your suggestion, I created a TabLib that could be included in the headlibs.jsp similar to the cq:includeClientLibs. In this case, it walks the content node and uses the resourceType and resourceSuperType to find components on the page. It then looks for a dependencies string[] property on the component and uses the HtmlLibraryManager to write the includes. It could be configured to render just CSS or JS if desired.  It seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

We have created components "upstream" OR wrapper components that include other components.

In the upstream case, they can add attributes to the request object (or play with cookies or ...)

In the "wrapper" case (Composition Pattern), the component 's other components.  We pass data into the included component by adding a String or Object to the request attribute that the inner component will look for.  After the inclusion, the wrapper component will then remove the attribute it added (so it doesn't accidentally pollute settings).
The "inner component" then is responsible for looking for specific attributes on the request object.

```
<%!
public String getPassedData(HttpServletRequest req, String attrName) {
    final Object passed = (req.getAttribute(attrName)==null) ? "" : req.getAttribute(attrName);
    if ( override.equals("") )
        return passed.toString();
    }
%>
```